# How would I convert a dictionary into a multi-dimensional list sorted by value?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm currently working on a small project (I'm relatively new to python) in which I have a dictionary of items (as an example):

```
dic = {
    'ab': 'a',
    'ac': 'a',
    'bc': 'b',
    'bd': 'b',
    'cd': 'c',
    'ce': 'c'
}
```

And would like to convert it into a list with each initial index being correlated to one of the values

```
sorted_lst[0][0] = ab
sorted_lst[2][1] = ce
```

and so forth. How would I go about doing this? Would it be easier to start with a sorted list rather than a dictionary?

The reason for doing so, is that I would like to print out columnal lists of guesses in which their assignment is derived from the initial letter of the guess. ie. something like:

```
ab  bc  cd
ac  bd  ce
```

So that the user can see their guesses in a more appealing way rather than just as an alphabetized list.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I suggest you step away from the code for a few minutes. Think about how you would do this by hand. What steps would you take? Describe those steps in words. Write those steps on a piece of paper or in a text editor. Getting a clear idea in your head of the steps to solve a problem is the first step towards writing code to solve that problem.

Comment: You *could* build a multi-dimensional list based on the key values but the way you do it would depend on the bounds of the key values. If the keys are all 2 characters and made up solely of lowercase letters then it's easy but if they're any different to that then it could be challenging

Comment: Don't use `list` or `sorted` as variable names, those are python builtins. (Also, in you case you have a dictionary, so rather call it `dic` or something like this)

Comment: shouldn't `sorted_lst[0][1]` be `ac`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

- We sort the unique values, then loop through each one and group the keys into a list.

---

```
data = {
    'ab': 'a',
    'ac': 'a',
    'bc': 'b',
    'bd': 'b',
    'cd': 'c',
    'ce': 'c'
}

sorted_data = []
for item in sorted(set(data.values())):
    sorted_data.append([key for key in data.keys() if data[key] == item])
# sorted_data = [['ab', 'ac'], ['bc', 'bd'], ['cd', 'ce']]
```

You can also use [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
sorted_data = {}
for key, item in data.items():
    sorted_data.setdefault(item, []).append(key)
sorted_data = list(sorted_data.values())
```

---

To print the values ​​you can then loop over each item:

```
for i in range(len(sorted_data[0])):
    for j in range(len(sorted_data)):
        print(sorted_data[j][i], end=" ")
    print("")
```

**output:**

```
ab bc cd 
ac bd ce
```

Comment: Thank you, the first example you gave was what I was looking for, just couldn't get there myself. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to transform your data to 2D:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k,v in dic.items():
    d[v].append(k)
    
sorted_lst = list(d.values())
# or to ensure sorting of the first level:
# sorted_lst = [d[k] for k in sorted(d)]

sorted_lst[0][1]
# ac

sorted_lst[2][1]
# ce
```

output: `[['ab', 'ac'], ['bc', 'bd'], ['cd', 'ce']]`

Comment: Thank you for the response, have never heard of defaultdict before but will check it out.

Comment: @SeanVanderaa you can do the same without defaultdict, you will need to manually check if the key exist, if not instantiate it with a list ;)